# ImageView CENTER_CROP dont work

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

Welcome all.

i have a LinearLayout that must show a ImageView. The imageView must fit all the width of the LinearLayout, so i used **match_parent** for the width, and it must keep the aspect ratio, so i used **wrap_content** for the height and setAdjustViewBounds to true. But something is not working because the width of the ImageView is correct (it fits the width of the linear layout) but the height of the imageView is wrong (the image is being cutted in the upper and the lower part)

**I tryed with all the scale types** (fit_center, fit_xy, center_crop, center_inside etc...) and i have problems with all of them (for example, if i use fit_center, the image is does not fit the full width of the ImageView, i can see two black spaces on left and right of the image, also i tried using FIT_CENTER without setAdjustViewBounds and i have the same problem)

HERE YOU HAVE AN SNAPSHOT:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hrKF.png

this is my code:

```
LinearLayout onlineHolder = this.holders.get(i);
onlineHolder.setLayoutParams(
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
onlineHolder.removeAllViews();
ImageView imgv = new ImageView(onlineHolder.getContext());
imgv.setLayoutParams(
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
imgv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imgv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
Bitmap b=res.getCachedBitmapWithWidth(this.width); //obtenemos el recurso cacheado con el width correspondiente
imageElement.setBitmap(b);
imgv.setImageBitmap(b);
onlineHolder.addView(imgv);
```

Thanks

**EDIT: it only works if i specify the width and the height of the imageview with absolute numbers. For example, if i put 400 (400 is the 50% of the screen, the layout width) width and 583 height, it works, but if i put MATCH_PARENT for width and WRAP CONTENT for height... it not works... why?**

Comment: what happens if you keep the onlineHolder params to be wrap_content and wrap_content while keeping the imgv layout params to be match_parent and match_parent? other things remaining the same.

Comment: the image is being displayed aligned to the left and with a huge black space on the right

Comment: I am a bit skeptical about setImageBitmap! setImageResource had worked for me. It does the scaling automatically

Comment: it only works if i specify the width and the height of the imageview with absolute numbers. For example, if i put 400 width and 583 height, it works, but if i put MATCH_PARENT for width and WRAP CONTENT for height... it not works... why?

Comment: As a caution, continually asking the same question, then deleting it, will eventually result in you being blocked from asking questions entirely. Try to edit your question instead, to clarify them.

Answer (score 1):

I have this one in XML and it works in the way you want. take a look.

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/attachedImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

But if you want to do it on the runtime, I suggest to create an XML this way and inflate the View on the runTime and add it to your parent layout. That will work for sure.

EDIT : How to inflate the ImageView.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_contains_image_view, null, false);
ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.attachedImage);
```

Comment: i tryed it in runtime, does not work. I need to do it with java code. It only works if i specify the width and the height of the imageview with absolute numbers. For example, if i put 400 width and 583 height, it works, but if i put MATCH_PARENT for width and WRAP CONTENT for height... it not works... why?

Comment: I checked the ScreenShot you uploaded and it seems like you need to make height match_parent instead of width of the ImageView. Try and let me know.

Comment: By the way meaning of runTime is the one with Java. You are also trying to do it on run time. But What I'm saying is instead of creating new ImageView, inflate that ImageView from XML resources.

Comment: Important! put ImageView at the top level of xml, and do not set cropping in code!